# Vista PC will not respond to pings on home network

Tags: router, windows-vista, home-networking, file-sharing, ping

I need some help with file & printer sharing with Windows Vista.

Home Network called is named WORKGROUP

Router:
Belkin N150 Wireless Router

3 PCs:
Win Vista Home Premium Desktop 64bit - connected to the router via a patch cable.
Win 7 Home Premium Laptop 64bit - wireless connection to router.
Win 8.1 Laptop 64bit - wireless connection to router.

All the PCs are configured for DCHP

Problem:
The Windows Vista laptop can not be PINGed from the Win 8 or Win 7 PCs
Error Message varies between “Ping request could not find HOSTNAME” or “Ping request timed out”
(For completeness, The Win 8 & Win 7 PCs can PING each other without a problem)

Yet the Win 8 & Win 7 PCs can be PINGed from the Vista Machine.
I can surf the Web on the Vista machine & Also can login & Play World of Warcraft
This wouldn't be a problem except that I need to share files & the printer that is attached to the Vista Desktop.

Troubleshooting steps taken:

On the Router:
Disabled Router's built in Firewall

On Vista PC:

Set the network type to private

Reset WINSOCK
Reset TCP/IP Stack

released/renewed ipconfig

created a firewall rule to allow the PC to respond to ICMPv4 inbound PING requests (when this didn't work, I turned off the firewall completely, see next step)

Disabled Windows Firewall
Uninstalled Anti-Virus/spyware Apps
Made sure network type was set to Private
Enabled Network Discovery, File sharing, Public Folder sharing, Printer Sharing, Media Sharing.

Went into network adapter settings:
Client for Microsoft Networks – Installed & enabled
QoS packet scheduler – Installed & enabled
File & Printer sharing for Microsoft Networks – Installed & enabled
TCP/IPv4 – Installed & enabled
Link Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O driver – Installed & enabled
Link Layer Topology Discovery Responder – Installed & enabled
(I left TCP/IPv6 unchecked, as this is a home network so no need for IP6)

NetBIOS over TCP/IP is enabled.

None of this works.  What am I missing?  I just can't figure this out. Something is preventing the Vista machine from being seen on the network. Thanks in advance for your assistance.